# Need help modifying hosts file using batch file

Tags: hosts

I know how to modify a hosts file using batch*, but is there a way to add a comment above the entry?

*echo 0.0.0.0 website.com

i.e.

#New website IP

0.0.0.0 website.com

Answer (score 0):

try `nano hosts` to edit the file with a proper text editor